# Check previous checkboxes when clicking a checkbox and saving all to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

I've been trying to find what I'll explain in a moment, but I only found parts of it and when I tried to put them together, it always failed. Rather than to show what I tried, I think it's better to explain and show a simple example of what I would like and hopefully someone can help me. Here's the example:

```
<div class="checkbox a">        
    Class A<br>                 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="a1" value="a1">                 
    <label>A1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="a2" value="a2">                 
    <label>A2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="a3" value="a3">                 
    <label>A3</label> 
</div>                          
                        
<div class="checkbox b">        
    Class B<br>                 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="b1" value="b1">                 
    <label>B1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="b2" value="b2">                 
    <label>B2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="b3" value="b3">                 
    <label>B3</label> 
</div>

<div class="checkbox c">
    Class C<br>                 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="c1" value="c1">                 
    <label>C1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="c2" value="c2">                 
    <label>C2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="c3" value="c3">                 
    <label>C3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="c4" value="c4">                 
    <label>C4</label> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="c5" value="c5">                 
    <label>C5</label>  
</div>
```

**PART 1** 
When you click **A3**, both **A2** and **A1** will be checked too. If you check **B2**, only **B2** and **B1** will be checked. 
Not a button to select all. *It kind of works like star ratings perhaps?*
**PART 2** 
When I refresh or close and reopen the link, all the checkboxes are still checked in the way I clicked them, so basically I'd like a code that save those choices preferably to the LocalStorage but if you think there's another way that allows me to save the choices, without connecting it to a database or something like that, then it should be okay too.

In all honesty I always had a hard time trying to explain or find what's in my mind, so hopefully all of it makes sense. In this example it only has Class A, B and C, but the thing I want to make will have much more classes. So no matter how many classes it has, it should remember all the checkboxes and unlock the previous checkboxes when clicked.
*e.g. when clicking **C4**, **C1** to **C3** will also be checked*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in two parts

### Part 1:

First, in your html I've added a class to each input element: `c{type of checkbox [a,b,c]}`. This was to easily identify each element in bulk.
Then I've added some javascript: First I've added the array that holds all the types of checkboxes. Then I created a foreach loop which assigns the `setCheckedBoxes(object, allChecks)` function to the `onclick` event of each checkbox. The `setCheckedBoxes` function sets all the appropriate checkboxes to either checked or not, depending if they are lower than, or equal to the number (`object[1]`) of the passed id (`object`).

```js
let checkBoxTypes = ["a", "b", "c", "ochtend", "middag"];

checkBoxTypes.forEach((item) => {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("checks " + item);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
      setCheckedBoxes(this.id, i);
    }
  }
});


function setCheckedBoxes(object, allChecks) {
  let objSplit = object.split('-');
  for (var i = 1; i <= allChecks; i++) {
    document.getElementById(objSplit[0] + '-' + i).checked = (i <= objSplit[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox a">
  Class A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks a" id="testa-1" value="a1">
  <label>A1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks a" id="testa-2" value="a2">
  <label>A2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks a" id="testa-3" value="a3">
  <label>A3</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox b">
  Class B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks b" id="testb-1" value="b1">
  <label>B1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks b" id="testb-2" value="b2">
  <label>B2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks b" id="testb-3" value="b3">
  <label>B3</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox c">
  Class C<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-1" value="c1">
  <label>C1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-2" value="c2">
  <label>C2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-3" value="c3">
  <label>C3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-4" value="c4">
  <label>C4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-5" value="c5">
  <label>C5</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox ochtend">
  Class ochtend<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-1" value="ochtend-1">
  <label>ochtend1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-2" value="ochtend-2">
  <label>ochtend2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-3" value="ochtend-3">
  <label>ochtend3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-4" value="ochtend-4">
  <label>ochtend4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-5" value="ochtend-5">
  <label>ochtend5</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox middag">
  Class middag<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-1" value="middag-1">
  <label>middag1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-2" value="middag-2">
  <label>middag2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-3" value="middag-3">
  <label>middag3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-4" value="middag-4">
  <label>middag4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-5" value="middag-5">
  <label>middag5</label>
</div>
```

### Part two

So, how would you save this data in `window.localStorage`?
First add the following lines to your code:

```js
const saveSpace = "database";
var storage = window.localStorage;
window.onload = getCheckedBoxes;
```

These are just 'shortcuts' for later, the last line makes sure that the function `getCheckedBoxes` is run every time we load the page, to set the checkboxes.

The following function will save the checkboxes in your `localStorage`

```js
function saveCheckedBoxes(object) {
  if (storage) {
    if(storage.getItem(saveSpace) != null) {
      let checkedBefore = JSON.parse(storage.getItem(saveSpace));
      checkedBefore[object[0]] = parseInt(object[1]);
      storage.setItem(saveSpace, JSON.stringify(checkedBefore));
    }
  }
}
```

It first checks if there's any `localStorage` available, then if there is an instance of our "database" en then it gets, and saves the data (`object` is the `id` of an checkbox for instance `a2`). The structure of `checkedBefore` is as follows: `{checkBoxType: Int, ...}` (with `checkBoxType` being the class after `checks`) like `{testa: 0,testb: 0,testc: 0,ochtend: 0,middag: 0}`.

The last function to be added retrieves the data on page load and calls `setCheckedBoxes` to set the checkboxes accordingly:

```js
function getCheckedBoxes() {
  if (storage) {
    if (storage.getItem(saveSpace) != null) {
      let checkedBefore = JSON.parse(storage.getItem(saveSpace));
      for (var type in checkedBefore) {
        if (checkedBefore.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
          setCheckedBoxes(type + '-' + (checkedBefore[type]), checkedBefore[type]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      //put here the text before the '-' of the id's
      storage.setItem(saveSpace, JSON.stringify({testa: 0,testb: 0,testc: 0,ochtend: 0,middag: 0}));
    }
  }
}
```

This function looks similar to the function before except that this one sets the default value of the data (if there isn't any yet) with

```js
      storage.setItem(saveSpace, JSON.stringify({testa: 0,testb: 0,testc: 0,ochtend: 0,middag: 0}));
```

And it parses the data and sets the checkboxes.

The full code can be found below:

```js
//put all of the checkbox types here
let checkBoxTypes = ["a", "b", "c", "ochtend", "middag"];
const saveSpace = "database";
var storage = window.localStorage;

window.onload = function() {
  checkBoxTypes.forEach((item) => {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("checks " + item);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].onclick = function() {
        setCheckedBoxes(this.id, i);
      }
    }
  });
  getCheckedBoxes();
}

function setCheckedBoxes(object, allChecks = 0) {
  let objSplit = object.split('-');

  //if the checkbox was checked already and the caller wasn't getCheckedBoxes then -1 how far the checkboxes should be checked
  if (document.getElementById(object) != null) {
    if (document.getElementById(object).checked == false && setCheckedBoxes.caller != getCheckedBoxes) {
      objSplit[1] -= 1;
    }
  }
  let max = allChecks;
  console.log("max: " + max);
  for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    document.getElementById(objSplit[0] + '-' + i).checked = (i <= objSplit[1]);
  }
  saveCheckedBoxes(objSplit);
}

function saveCheckedBoxes(object) {
  if (storage) {
    if (storage.getItem(saveSpace) != null) {
      let checkedBefore = JSON.parse(storage.getItem(saveSpace));
      checkedBefore[object[0]] = parseInt(object[1]);
      storage.setItem(saveSpace, JSON.stringify(checkedBefore));
    }
  }
}

function getCheckedBoxes() {
  if (storage) {
    if (storage.getItem(saveSpace) != null) {
      let checkedBefore = JSON.parse(storage.getItem(saveSpace));
      console.log(checkedBefore);
      for (var type in checkedBefore) {
        if (checkedBefore.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
          console.log(type + '-' + (checkedBefore[type]));
          setCheckedBoxes(type + '-' + (checkedBefore[type]), checkedBefore[type]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      //put here the text before the '-' of the id's
      storage.setItem(saveSpace, JSON.stringify({
        testa: 0,
        testb: 0,
        testc: 0,
        ochtend: 0,
        middag: 0
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox a">
  Class A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks a" id="testa-1" value="a1">
  <label>A1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks a" id="testa-2" value="a2">
  <label>A2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks a" id="testa-3" value="a3">
  <label>A3</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox b">
  Class B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks b" id="testb-1" value="b1">
  <label>B1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks b" id="testb-2" value="b2">
  <label>B2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks b" id="testb-3" value="b3">
  <label>B3</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox c">
  Class C<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-1" value="c1">
  <label>C1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-2" value="c2">
  <label>C2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-3" value="c3">
  <label>C3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-4" value="c4">
  <label>C4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks c" id="testc-5" value="c5">
  <label>C5</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox ochtend">
  Class ochtend<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-1" value="ochtend-1">
  <label>ochtend1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-2" value="ochtend-2">
  <label>ochtend2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-3" value="ochtend-3">
  <label>ochtend3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-4" value="ochtend-4">
  <label>ochtend4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks ochtend" id="ochtend-5" value="ochtend-5">
  <label>ochtend5</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox middag">
  Class middag<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-1" value="middag-1">
  <label>middag1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-2" value="middag-2">
  <label>middag2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-3" value="middag-3">
  <label>middag3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-4" value="middag-4">
  <label>middag4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checks middag" id="middag-5" value="middag-5">
  <label>middag5</label>
</div>
```

#### Disclaimer

Apparently `window.localStorage` is not secure in jsFiddle, thus this example won't fully work in this fiddle, however it can be tested here:
[chielchiel.nl/test/ls/](http://chielchiel.nl/test/ls/)

#### Edit

It should now all be working. You should put the id's in the format of `{someIdentifier}-#` like `classA-1`.
Hope this helps, if not please comment!

Comment: Ohmy it works like a charm! thank you so much for the detailed solution!

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I'm not that good with coding. I was wondering if it was possible to uncheck `a1/b1/c1 etc.` because now when you click on it, it stays checked. 

Another thing I was wondering is, if I change the ID _(e.g. `id="a1"` to `id="test1")`_ it stops working, is it possible to change this? so that I change the IDs to more than just a letter and number, because now it seems like I can only use A+number to Z+number. 

_(e.g. `id="classa1"` / `id="classab1"` / `id="classabc1"` / `id="testabc1"`)_ so that it doesn't matter how many IDs I have

Comment: @Tadakun ill take a look at it!

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @Tadakun it should now be working, check the website for a full working example

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, when using your code, everything works, I tried to add **D** `(id=testd-1 etc)` and adding it to the script, it still works, but everything after that like the Letter **E** or **F** doesn't save. I tried changing the `testa` to `hello` / `classa` to see if it works but that doesn't work either, only `testa, testb, testc, testd` seem to work for me. is it possible to maybe add 3 more classes for example to the code, all of them with random a class and IDs that don't start with test? like `ochtend-1,2,3`, `middag-1,2,3`, `avond-1,2,3` for example haha